# WordPress Localization/Translation

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I know `__()` this function as double underscore function, some people call translate string. What's the actual name of `__()`, `_e`, `_ex()` those functions in WordPress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

__() and _e() are the simplest functions: they return or echo the translated string. Their usage should be obvious: one string, one translation.

The remaining function _ex is a combination of _e and _x: it echoes a translated string using a context.

If You can get more idea with example then Go through this tutorial link: [What’s the difference between __(), _e(), _x(), and _ex()?](http://wpengineer.com/2237/whats-the-difference-between-__-_e-_x-and-_ex/)